# Cannot set unsafe header "Host" in react using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, postman

Trying to use axios get to obtain data from an API. Unfortunately the page is not allowing a header-set of 'host' with axios. Without the 'host' header the server returns a 404. However, returns data on postman using this url and setting a header.

```
const axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
  "content-Type": "application/json",
  "Host": "marketcheck-prod.apigee.net"
 },
 credentials: "same-origin"
 }


componentDidMount(){
    this.getData()
    console.log('fired')
}


getData =() => axios.get('http://api.marketcheck.com/v1//search?start=0&rows=50&Content-Type="applications/json"&{{api_key}}', axiosConfig).then(res => {
    console.log('what')
    this.setState({
        data: res.data
    })
    console.log(res.data);
    console.log(this.state.data);
    console.log('anything')
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('no');
    })
```

I expect data to be returned, but actual output is "Cannot set unsafe header Host" and a 404.

Comment: Browsers won't let you set the Host header, and you don't need it anyways here. Just `axios.get('https://marketcheck-prod.apigee.net...')` if that's the host you want to access.

Comment: i think a configuration is missing in the api backend side however it works with postman i counter that before api endpoint working on postman and not in browser i fix it with a backend cors configuration if you own the api you can check that

Comment: The browser sets Host for you automatically.